# I reinstalled Entity Framework and now it's giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I initially got a problem in DB due to which I re-installed entity framework (earlier my version was 5.0 and now I installed 6.1.3), I am connected to SQL server but now I am getting an error which says:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Please tell me how to resolve it.
Thanks

Comment: check you web.config file for appropriate version of newly installed entity framework

Comment: ^ here's mine connection string , from where i can get new connection string for new EF?

Comment: <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

Comment: the problem is not with connection string. it depends on which version of EF you set on the assemblyBinding

Comment: <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

Comment: is it mine EF string pls tell me how to change it?

Comment: and you should not expose your SQL connection account credentials anywhere

Comment: how to set version of EF?

Comment: check for entity framework version under runtime -> assemblyBinding config in web.config file

Comment: and how did you update EF in your application ?

Comment: using nuget package

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your web.config runtime -> assemblyBinding config section ?

Comment: in runtime-> assemblyBinding where should i check? there's no EF field

Comment: can you please check anywhere in your project it's used EF config with 5.0 version ?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749175/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-after-downgrading-ef-5-0-0-0

Comment: No in web confiq there's nowhere EF 5.0 rather there's EF 6.1.3

Comment: refer this link to learn how to set the correct version of EF in web.config file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749175/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-after-downgrading-ef-5-0-0-0

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your EntityFrame Work using this command from

update-Package EntityFramework

Comment: VS -> Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that the versions on packages.config and web.config match