# : System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"/>
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="9.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

I tried to uninstall and re install EF 
[do all the Solution hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749175/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-after-downgrading-ef-5-0-0-0)
and i can't change target framework to 5 because 
i use automaper

Comment: What version of .net? I see you've installed it for 4.6.2 but what are you using?

Comment: i'm sure i'm use .net 4.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Check a couple of things.

- Make sure the version of `EF` installed supports the version of
  `.Net` you're using.
- uninstall and reinstall
- Make sure Nuget installed EntityFramework package
- Make sure that all the projects are targeting the same .NET
  Framework.

EDIT:

Check your refrences for every `EntityFramework.dll` Go and check the version for each one.

Comment: I'm sure of all the things you said.
but it still don't work 
thanks.

Comment: don't don't worry it's v 5

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, i just make sure that i am referencing the correct framework .Net in all the projects in web config

i change this

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
```

to

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Comment: I tried to uninstall and re install EF [do all the Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749175/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-after-downgrading-ef-5-0-0-0)hear and i can't change target framework to 5 because i use automaper

Comment: share source code on it git or some ware else , so that i can check. if you have no issue.